# Два компонента делают пустую страницу

Tags: php, битрикс

Почему возникает пустая страница при расположении двух компонентов `smart.filter` и `catalog_section`?

Ставила между двумя компонентами знаки комментариев — ни к чему это не привело. Если убрать второй компонент, то отображается фильтр. А если вставляешь второй компонент, то все пропадает. Такое впечатление, что все элементы не отображает.

```html
<?php
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Масла");
/*-----------------------------*/?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter", 
    "uni_catalog_smart_filter", 
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_catalog", /*Тип инфоблока*/
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
        "SECTION_ID" => "3",
        "SECTION_CODE" => "maslo",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
        "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "Y",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
        "INSTANT_RELOAD" => "Y",
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(
            0 => "BASE",
        ),
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "Y",
        "XML_EXPORT" => "N",
        "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
        "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "POPUP_POSITION" => "bottom",
   
        "SECTION_CODE_PATH" => "",
        "SMART_FILTER_PATH" => $_REQUEST["SMART_FILTER_PATH"],
        "CURRENCY_ID" => "RUB"
    ),
    false
);?>
<?/*------------------------------------------------------*/?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.section", "uni_catalog_section_filter", array(
       "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_catalog",
       "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
       "SECTION_ID" => "3",
       "SECTION_CODE" => "maslo",
       "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
          0 => "",
          1 => "",
       ),
       "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
       "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
       "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
       "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
       "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",
       "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
       "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
       "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
       "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "10000",
       "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "1",
       "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
          0 => "BREND",
          1 => "CML2_ARTICLE",
          2 => "DNEY_DOSTAVKI",
          3 => "",
       ),
       "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
          0 => "ID",
          1 => "",
       ),
       "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
          0 => "CML2_LINK",
          1 => "",
       ),
       "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => '',
       "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" =>'' ,
       "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "",
       "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "",
       "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "30",
       "SECTION_URL" => "",
       "DETAIL_URL" => "",
       "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/cart/",
       "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
       "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
       "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
       "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
       "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
       "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
       "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
       "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N",
       "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
       "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
       "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
       "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
       "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
       "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
       "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
       "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
       "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
       "SET_TITLE" => "N",
       "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
       "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
   
       "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
       "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
       "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
       "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
       ),
       "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
       "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
       "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(
       ),
       
       "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => ""
       ),
       false
    );?>
<?php require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Лимит установлен в 10000 товаров. Поставила 30. Вопрос закрыт.